# What do people use for CN with inetOrgPerson in LDAP directories

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema-design

I've been using `givenName+" "+surname` for the CN field and I woke up screaming last night 'what about John Smith'? I can imagine any large organization employing multiple people with the same name. So of course this isn't going to work. What do people use instead?

**EDIT** Note: in `inetOrgPerson` the CN is part of the DN.

**EDIT** Note: in this situation I am expecting to grow to hundreds of thousands of user entries.

Comment: `commonName` or `cn` is a multi-valued attribute. An additional value can be inserted into 'John Smith' to identify the entry further. The primary key of the entry, the `distinguished name` or `dn` is unique per hosted or shadowed DIT. Also, do not fall into the trap of trying to interact with LDAP on a vendor-specific basis. Stick to LDAP standards and avoid the trap of doing things the 'Microsoft way' or 'OpenLDAP way'.

Comment: @Terry Gardner thanks. inetOrgPerson isn't OpenLDAP-specific, correct?

Comment: No. inetOrgPerson is defined in an RFC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a LDAP Directory, whatever if it's OpenLDAP or Active-Directory, a rule is that a DistinguishName (DN) must be unique, independently of the attribute (or the attributes) used to constitute the Relative Distinguish Name (RDN).

How do people make sure that it's unique :

1. I would say that in a small business the guy who creates the entry in the directory guarantee that it's unique, first by knowledge, second by preliminary search. If a duplicate appears he finds some solutions like 'John E Smith'. Using this solution if the name changes (marriage, divorce etc.), the LDAP record has to "move" from one DN to another. It's better to avoid changing the DN of an entry whenever possible, but in a small directory it's not important.
2. In a medium business the uniqueness is most of the time given by the employee ID coming from human resources. For example FR12345678. I saw, in big companies, people logging in with their employee ID. For the thing I describe here, it's more standart to use the `uid` attribute to name an object in spite of `cn` (but some directories don't let you choise of the naming attribute, I think it's a 
   X500 feature).
3. In most directories (not in AD) you can use more than one attribute to compose the RDN. For example `sn=Assin+TelephoneNumber=1234` is a valid RDN in an openLDAP and it can make sense in a PBX.
   One more thing

In some directories (designed for system administration) some attributes are tested by the server side as unique all over the tree. That's the case of `sAMAccountName` or `userPrincipalName` in Active-Directory and they are used for loging purpose. Using the CN attribute with "given-Name Name" oblige the administrators to guarantee uniqueness. You can use unique attribute in OpenLDAP for that in the database definition in `slapd.conf`, add :

```
# index since the unique overlay will search for matching mail attributes
index mail eq

overlay unique
unique_attributes mail
```

If unique overlay is not compiled in, you'll need to recompile with :

```
./configure ... --enable-unique
```

Comment: In Puerto Rico, and most Hispanic countries, we append the Mothers maiden name, example: FRANK RIVERA RODRIGUEZ, where RODRIGUEZ is the Mothers maiden name. This is standard usage in Hispanic countries and adds more uniqueness, although not total. If we cannot achieve uniqueness, we append the pk_id (autonumber) after Mothers maiden name to guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to JPBlanc's answer with some of my experience.  We have several ldap servers/trees where I work.  Our AD server is using the DisplayName as the value of the CN.  Out of 4K+ users we have only had a few instances where duplicates have occurred.  I believe the default action there is to tack a 1 on the value if there is a dupe.  It is surprisingly rare even with a high turn over rate in the largest section of that user base.  We have two different e-directory trees that are linked to each other and those use the username.  Username is first initial + last name.  Any duplicates there have an incrementing number attached to them.  As you can imagine that happens a lot with the Browns and the Smiths and other common names.  Another tree that is an ADLDS (formerly ADAM) directory uses a uniquely generated number for each new entry as the CN.  It is basically an auto-incremented number that is controlled by an external loading process.  Lastly we have a directory for external partners (think independent agents) that uses a combination of email address + an id number as the CN.

I do a lot of maintenance work on the user bases and my least favorite scheme is the externally generated number.  If I get a support call about Joe Brown in all of the other systems I can at least have an idea of where I need to browse to find him.  Sure a simple search filter will give me all of the Browns but I still have to write it and execute it.  So my advice is to use some part of the name for the CN and ensure uniqueness somehow.  From an administration point of view it will be a bit easier.  Really the CN is important but you'll be dealing with the rest of the user attributes far more so don't sweat it too badly.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had come to much the same conclusion. We are planning on tens of thousands of users at least: they are really subscribers, so over the years this directory could get enormous, even hundreds of thousands. As another data point, at one place I worked where there are 12,000 employees and a floating army of contractors I got up to epitt4 over a period of about ten years, as I was one of the floating contractors and IT couldn't recognize my prior existence(s).